# How to make Bundler recognize location declarations of indirect dependencies?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am working on a small team and have developed several gems for internal use.  These gems are variously interdependent and are hosted on my Github account.  When I declare dependencies on these gems, I always put in the declaring `Gemfile`: `:git => 'url/for/gem/on/github'`.  But I am running into some confusing behavior from Bundler-- I would think that:

- if gem A depends on and declares github-hosted B in A's Gemfile
- and B depends on and declares github-hosted C in B's Gemfile
- then when I run `bundle install` from A...
- Bundler should fetch B from github, as declared in A's Gemfile
- then fetch C from github, as declared in B's Gemfile

But Bundler complains that it can't find C.  If I declare C in A's `Gemfile` with the proper location, then it does not complain.  Am I right in inferring that Bundler does not actually look at dependency `Gemfile`s at all, and rather just looks at their `gemspec`?  And if I am, is there a better solution to the problem I describe than declaring C as a dependency of A directly in A's `Gemfile`?

UPDATE: It seems that if you could declare a Github account as a gem source in the `Gemfile`, then this problem would be solved.  Is this possible?

Comment: To clarify, does B have C as a `runtime_dependency` in B's `.gemspec`?

Comment: Yes B declares C as a `runtime_dependency` in both B's `.gemspec` and in the `Gemfile`.  It has to be declared in the `Gemfile` as well because a location can't be declared (I think?) in the `.gemspec`

Comment: Yes, you're right. `.gemspec` doesn't support any `:git` type arguments while adding the `runtime_dependency`s.

Answer (score 2):

We recently had to tackle a very similar situation with internal gems depending on each other. We already used an internal git host (GitLab) but had the same problems with not being able to declare bundle style `git:`and `branch:` attributes in the gemspec.

The solution for us was to set up internal gem hosting as well. Using geminabox it's *really* easy to get a gem host up and running. run `gem install geminabox` and create a folder for your web service (we use passenger, ymmw):

```
gems/
  public/
  tmp/
    restart.txt
  gems/
  config.ru
```

The edit `config.ru` so something like this:

```
require "rubygems"
require "geminabox"

Geminabox.data = "gems"
run Geminabox
```

And point passenger at the gems/public folder and it'll start up as a normal rack app for you to play with. Simply add the url to the service in the gemfiles and skip the whole git problem for internal gems, that's my advice :)

More info on geminabox can be found on their github page: https://github.com/geminabox/geminabox